# Enable a display device and set resolution using Pinvoke

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, monitor

I am able to successfully change the resolution on the devices got through EnumDisplayDevices which are active but which devices are not active I can not set their resolution. Is there any way to activate/enable the disabled display devices programatically like I can do this in GUI by clicking the Detect button ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7pSK.png)).
Please note I am using C# .Net to achieve this and for changing the screen resolution I am using ChangeDisplaySettingsEx.